# Леность, лень и лениво

Tags: этимология, недопустимая-метка

А чем, собственно, отличаются понятия "лень" и "леность"? А еще в последнее время появилось такое прилагательное как "лениво": "Мне лениво туда идти". Понятно, что такого слова нет, но мне кажется оно вполне логичным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Леность - склонность к лени. Антоним - трудолюбие.
Лень - проявление лености в конкретный момент или ситуации. Антоним (неточный) - труд.

Впрочем, часто выступают как синонимы.

Насчет "лениво" - да, "официально" слова такого пока нет. Но лично мне очень нравится. 
Просто во фразах типа "Мне лень делать это" лень выступает в функции наречия (если не категории состояния), хотя формальных признаков наречия не имеет. "Лениво" решает эту проблему.

Comment: Мне лениво - тоже слово состояния.

Comment: Ну да. О том и речь. И при этом оно даже внешне не напоминает существительное.

Comment: Мне тоже нравится слово "лениво"! По-моему, оно просто... удобное.